# What is the best way to serialize contenteditable fields into a JSON object for saving to a model?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, backbone.js, marionette

Primarily for layout purposes I would prefer to use `<div>` tags in my views with `contenteditable="true"` for editing a model's attributes. That said, I've found it difficult to find a reliable solution for serializing these elements' values for saving to the model.

Is there a reliable way to serialize the contents of a groups of `<div contenteditable="true">` elements?

Comment: `innerHTML`?  Serialize how?

Comment: kindly show us ur fiddle so we can do on how to serialize..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the content editable divs in a container, you can iterate over the children of the container and grab each value and store it in an object:

```
handleForm: function () {
  var formData = {};
  var value;

  $('#container').children('div[contenteditable]').each(function() {
    value = this.innerHTML;
    if (value) {
      formData[this.id] = value;
    }
  });

  // do stuff with formData object 
  this.model.create(formData); /* or this.collection.create(formData);
}
```